# Mapping a property to a new instance of a class using AutoMapper

Tags: automapper

If I have a class, Foo, looking like this...

```
class Foo
{
    public string TelephoneNumber1;
    public string TelephoneNumber2;
    public string TelephoneNumber3;
    public string TelephoneNumber4;
}
```

is it possible to use AutoMapper to map to this class...

```
class Bar
{
    public ContactInfo[] Contacts;
}
```

where ContactInfo is...

```
class ContactInfo
{
    public string TelephoneNumber;
}
```

if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly. You could map a Foo with a string[] of telephone numbers:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string[] TelephoneNumbers { get; set; }
}

Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, Bar>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Contacts, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TelephoneNumbers));

Mapper.CreateMap<string, ContactInfo>()
    .ConvertUsing(value => new ContactInfo { TelephoneNumber = value });
```

Then you could map like so:

```
Bar bar = Mapper.Map<Foo, Bar>(foo);
```